The rig (bones) that I have created for the hair (mesh) does not follow said hair during the animation
I have a problem in which the rig (bones) that I have created for the hair (mesh) does not follow said hair during the animation, although I activated the "keep transformation" option it only works when I move the mesh manually but not during an animation, in said animation the hair can go very far from its original position while the rig continues in the same place and it is a problem since when you need to activate a part of the rig the hair is deformed pointing to the current position of the rig. rig and not where it should be which is glued to the hair. How can I make the rig follow the hair during the animation?
https://youtu.be/tQthLb0cOA4
https://youtu.be/t8MnMjE5WHk

Hello, you probably need to remove its vertices from some vertex groups? Maybe share your file so that we can take a look?

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Hello, thank you in advance for reading me, I would like to ask you if you could make a video or provide me with help in which when creating a rig for a character's hair, said rig moves position when I create an animation, that is, I move a bone individual of the character's legs and this causes the character to walk forward, but the rig created for the hair stays in the same place in which it was created and does not adhere to the hair so that when the hair moves one unit forward Moving forward, the rig for said hair also moves one unit in the same direction.

Although I used the "set parent to object (keep transform)" function, it only works to move the parts of the hair that I painted red, but it does not work for the rig to chase the hair to which it was "parented" during the character's movements from one position to another when I play the animation. I hope you can understand my problem.
